# SQL Lookup one column in multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have some clue how to do this, but I wanted to bounce off ideas and do it in the most efficient way.
I want to join Table1 with Table2 and get the Amount from Table2. The key in Table1 may/may not be found in one or more of 4 columns in Table2.
Keep in mind, in the actual usecase, Table1 and Table2 are subqueries to get the data needed so I want to keep the overall query as less complicated as possible.
Ignore the dots in the sample data below, I put them only to align the values.

Table1 has the following:
**Col1**
a
b
c
d
e
f

Table2 has the following:
**Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Amount**
a....................................5.00
b..................b...............20.00
...........c...............c.......35.00
....................d...............15.00
e.........e.......e...............22.00

Result:
**Col1    Amount**
a.........5.00
b........20.00
c........35.00
d........15.00
e........22.00
f.........NULL

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you want to "bounce off ideas and do it in the most efficient way" then why don't you share what you've got so far and let us start from there?

Comment: OK, will send tonight

Answer (score 1):

Given your data, the following should work:

```
select t1.col1, t2.amount
from table1 t1 left join
     table2
     on t1.col1 = coalesce(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) ;
```

This is standard SQL, so it should work in almost any database.

Comment: sorry this took so long. thx for the idea, but I forgot to mention that the remaining columns in table2 will not necessarily be null, they will be populated with values.